# Correct way to replace CHeaderCtrl with custom version in a CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, winapi, clistctrl

CListCtrl has a CHeaderCtrl 'built-in' and we want to override it with something customized, i.e a class which derives from CHeaderCtrl.

What's the best/correct way to do this, assuming we have a dialog CMyDlg which contains a CListCtrl m_List, and a custom header CCustomHeader.

Comment: AFAIK there is no possibility to replace only the header control. I think you have to derive the whole list control and put your behavior in there.

Comment: Would you share a simple example of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call [CWnd::SubclassWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wt95892(VS.80).aspx) from your CCustomHeader member variable.

```
m_Header.SubclassWindow(m_List.GetHeaderCtrl()->GetSafeHwnd());
```

Comment: It's a good idea to do this in PreSubClassWindow of the list control (provided you derive your own list control).

Answer (score 0):

Derive a class from `CListCtrl` and implement the handlers for the notification messages you need. The messages are named with LVN_ for messages about the list control and its items, and also HDN_ for things about the header control.

Comment: How does this fit in with CListCtrl::GetHeaderCtrl?

Comment: The messages of the header control are routed to its container, the list control. If you need to modify the header, you have to use `this->GetHeaderCtrl()->whatever`.